# Bash: batch resize images if width/height exceeds a specific value

Tags: bash, imagemagick

Is there any way to batch resize images if input image width or height exceeds a specific value (Linux or Mac OS X, command line)?

I found here a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273203/how-to-resize-image-only-if-width-exceeds-with-graphics-image-magick), but that one is for one image only.

Comment: What prevents you from using a loop, or `xargs`, or GNU Parallel, or whatever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e
maxwidth="1900"  # in pixels, the widest image you want to allow.

#find all .jpg in current dir and subdirectories
FILES="$(find . -iname '*.jpg')"

for imagefile in $FILES
do
if [ -f "$imagefile" ]; then
imgwidth=`sips --getProperty pixelWidth "$imagefile" | awk '/pixelWidth/ {print $2}'`
else
    echo "Oops, "$imagefile" does not exist." 
    exit
fi

if [ $imgwidth -gt $maxwidth ]; then
    echo " - Image too big. Resizing..."
    sips --resampleWidth $maxwidth "$imagefile" > /dev/null 2>&1  # to hide sips' ugly output 
    imgwidth=`sips --getProperty pixelWidth "$imagefile" | awk '/pixelWidth/ {print $2}'`
    imgheight=`sips --getProperty pixelHeight "$imagefile" | awk '/pixelHeight/ {print $2}'`
    echo " - Resized "$imagefile" to $imgwidth""px wide by $imgheight""px tall";
fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

With `mogrify` from the ImageMagick suite maybe:

```
mogrify -resize 1024x768\> *.jpg
```

Resize all jpegs exceeding 1024x768 down proportionally. Try it on a COPY of your images first. Add `-path output` to get results written to a subdirectory called `output` - make it first with `mkdir output`.

It's the trailing `>` that specifies to shrink the image only if the dimensions exceed the given value - from https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry:

> widthxheight>     Shrinks an image with dimension(s) larger than the corresponding width and/or height argument(s).

The trailing slash is preceded by a backslash so the (bash) shell doesn't perceive it as a redirection of `stdout` to a file.